# Texture rotation - Blender render

Tags: texturing, materials, uv

I have a problem with texture and material rotation.
I am building a structure and I must "split" it in more mesh because I need to upload it in a online game with certain size/texture limits.

As you can see f I made 3 objects .

[image: Pic 1]

[image: Pic 2]

Mesh 1 is rotated on Z at 180° - Mesh 3 is rotaded on Z at 240°. If you look at object 1 and 2 the textures are ok.

Problem is with object 3 rotated Z at 240°.

**I can unwrap the material only in "Project from View (Bounds)" mode.** (because of the above mentioned limitations)

I unwrapped object 1 at 180° in top view . I used a image mapped X1 - Y5.
I copied object 1 and rotated it to 240° (and I made a "single" user).
But material/texture does not match.

There is a way to rotate the marble image? 
I know that it is possible in Blender Cycles but I am using Blender render.

Thank you very much and advance :-)

Comment: Try to rotate the uv meshes in UVMap Editor.

Comment: I can not. I can use only Project from view.  The texture size is exactly the same size of the mesh.